# Preload web-page request in SFSafariViewController, before presenting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

Hi I'm using **SFSafariViewController** in my app.
I want to **preload / pre cache** **Webpage** URL request in **SFSafariViewController**.
So that web page is already loaded and rendered before presenting it. I get on an average 5 seconds before user triggers button to show web page, i want to utilise that time to preload web page.